# Make content overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make something where I need to duplicate all the entries (multiple times) and then later I would like to make it spin and land on a colour slowly, etc. I'm now just getting stuck at duplicating the colours, how can I make it so the new colours are overflowing, without doubling the width?

I want it so that the colours go out of the `wrapper` div. Now they are just distributing themselves.

Any ideas?

```js
$(document).on("click", ".duplicate", function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.wrapper .inner');

  $wrapper.find('.color').each(function() {
    $wrapper.append($(this).clone());
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 12px auto;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .color {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="color" style="background:red;width:231%"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background:purple;width:111%"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background:orange;width:91%"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class='duplicate'>
  Duplicate
</button>
```

Comment: `how can I make it so the new colours are overflowing, without doubling the width?` --> like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/z41m29gs/8/

Comment: by the way did you know something called linear-gradient ? it can make your life easier

Comment: @TemaniAfif not really usefull for what I'm trying to achieve, about your fiddle though, when I run it, when there are no duplicates it isn't spread around the whole wrapper, which I'd like it to be.

Edit: the first three have to be spread over the full width of the wrapper.

Comment: i simply update the width for testing you can make it 33% like this https://jsfiddle.net/z41m29gs/18/ ... by the way can you show us a screenshot

Comment: Hi! I converted your Fiddle [to an inline snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for you.

Comment: @TemaniAfif what if a colour would have a bigger part, I would be a lot of fiddling around :3.

This does work but I would also like to have to work when multiple widths are applied, using javascript, without css.

Edit: see updated widths in snippet.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have two items in the same position in document flow you need to wrap them in a parent with `position:relative` and give one of them `position:absolute; top:0;left:0`. Also note that if your element doesn't have any content, you might need to define it's `height` and `width`. To make it same size as parent, you can give it `top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;`.

Here's a demo started from [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/1wa18o9L/). You might want to inspect DOM after you press "Duplicate". I made it revert to original, so you can do it multiple times.

But do note your question is currently unclear. I'm afraid you lost me at *"to make it spin and land on a colour slowly"*. It's truly poetic, but won't get you very far on SO...

Comment: Making it land on a colour slowly is done by using a cubig-bezier. But I know I am not so good at explaining my issue as I'm not finding the correct words as my native language isn't english, but I made this image of what I want. https://i.imgur.com/iG9Px4j.png

Comment: No, I want it to to duplicate, and just add the divs, but then the duplicates divs should be invisible (they should be overflowing).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are simply over complicating this. All what you need is a reapeated linear-gradient like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 12px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 6px;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .color {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.new {
  margin-top:5px;
  height:25px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red,red 54%,purple 54%, purple 80%,orange 0);
  background-size:100% 100%;
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    background-position:0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position:-1000px 0;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="color" style="background:red;width:231%"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background:purple;width:111%"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background:orange;width:91%"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="new"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, that seems to fit my needs, but what if I were to have it like scroll over the row ten times, not going back?

Comment: @OrpheuZ adjust the animation ... i make it going back with alternate, but you are not obliged